# ファイルが存在したらそれをsourceする処理をスマートに書くには？

Tags: bash

```
if [[ ! -o posix && -z "${BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR:-}" ]]; then
    if [[ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]]; then
        . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
    elif [[ -f /etc/bash_completion ]]; then
        . /etc/bash_completion
    fi
fi
```

現状では上記のように書いているのですが、同じファイル名を2回書くのは冗長に思えます。
より良い書き方はありますでしょうか？

bashの組み込みコマンドでなければ`find PATH/TO/DIR -name FILENAME -execdir cat {} \+`のように書けるのですが……。

Comment: 興味関心から聞くのですが、 `[[ ! -o posix ]]` で、「 posix じゃなかったら (find が使えなかったら)」前提でのスクリプトにしようとしているのだと思っています。 find が使えない unix 系システム、というのをあまり知らないのですが、これは、実際にそういう場面があったのでしょうか。。？

Comment: @Yuki Inoue `! -o posix`はbashがposixモードでないことを確認しています。bash-completionではshには存在しない内部コマンドを利用しているからです。

Comment: なるほど。。であれば、素直に find を使ってしまっていいと個人的には思っています。 posix 規格にも入っていて、基本的な unix シェルであれば入っているであろうこと、 `-exec cat '{}' \+` であればどの `find` であってもサポートしていそうなので。。  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html

Comment: そう出来たらいいのですが、`find`の`-exec`系のアクションではbashの内部コマンドは実行できないんですよね……。ちなみに`xargs`でも同様です。

Comment: ああ、たしかに、 exec ではそうでした。 bash 内部関数は使えない。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自分だったら、重複とか気になりだしたら、普通に変数導入したり関数挟んだりして対応すると思います。仮に、自分が重複省くとしたら、以下のようになると思います。

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

try_source_first_existed() {
    for file in "$@"
    do
        if [ -f "$file" ]
        then
            . "$file"
            return $?
        fi
    done
}

if [[ ! -o posix && -z "${BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR:-}" ]]; then
    try_source_first_existed \
        /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion \
        /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`man bash`の`[[ expression ]]`セクションに次のような記述がありました。

> そのほか、二項演算子 =~ もあります。
>   (中略)
>   正規表現中の括弧による部分式にマッチした部分文字列は、配列変数 BASH_REMATCH に保存されます。
>   BASH_REMATCH のインデックス 0 の要素は、文字列のうち正規表現全体にマッチした部分になります。

```
if [[ ! -o posix && -z "${BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR:-}" ]]; then
    if [[ "/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion" =~ .* && -f "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" ]]; then 
        . "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    elif [[ "/etc/bash_completion" =~ .* && -f "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" ]]; then
        . "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    fi  
fi
```

上記のように書くことで多少すっきりしました。

(改善点)
* shellcheckでSC2049及びSC2050の警告が出る